# Yii2 changing session name for dividing frontend & backend user login not working

Tags: php, session, yii2-advanced-app

Actually, I am trying to change the session "PHPSESSID" to "PHPFRONTSESSID" and "PHPBACKSESSID" respectively for dividing login for users frontend and backend. I have hosted it in GODADDY shared hosting and it was working fine before but not working now. It is not changing the session name it is using same name "PHPSESSID" for frontend and backend.

frontend/config/main.php

```
'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
             'identityCookie' => [
                'name' => '_frontendUser', // unique for frontend
            ]
        ],
         'session' => [
            'name' => 'PHPFRONTSESSID',
            'savePath' => __DIR__ . '/../runtime', // a temporary folder on frontend

        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Chnage in your config file and check it
**Cookie Backend**

```
'identityCookie' => [
                'name' => '_backendIdentity',
                'path'=>'/admin',
                'httpOnly' => true,
            ],
```

**Cookie Frontend**

```
'identityCookie' => [
                    'name' => '_frontendIdentity',
                    'path'=>'/', 
                    'httpOnly' => true,
                ],
```

**Session Backend**

```
'session' => [
            'name' => 'session_backend'
        ],
```

**Session Frontend**

```
'session' => [
            'name' => 'session_frontend'
        ],
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But the issue with the sessions still exists.
Do you have any other solution.